# Class disappears from the Class View pane in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm working with an MFC/C++ project in Visual Studio 2008. The project compiles and runs just fine, but what happens is that after some time (not immediately) one of the classes disappears from the class view pane

[image]

and when I open its `.cpp` or `.h` files I cannot navigate to any of the class methods because this down-down control

[image]

is also empty.

Is there any way to determine what's causing this? Or at least pin-point the spot in my code that makes VS not see the class?

PS1. What's also weird is that VS sees the class if I delete all .pdb and .ncb and other auxiliary files and reload the project back into VS, but it disappears again after 10 minutes or so.

PS2. The screenshots above are not my actual project.

Comment: @cha: Do you want to give any hint how to find that very popular tool?

Comment: Intellisense has never been robust - with VS2008, closing the solution and deleting the .ncb was a very common workaround. It's not your code that's the problem.

Comment: @RogerRowland: I have about 50 other solutions on the same machine that are opened with the same VS2008 and I've never seen anything like this. That is why I thought that something in the code of this particular project makes this bug come out.

Comment: Yes, I understand - it was the same with me, some projects didn't show the problem. However, changing the code just to overcome a VS2008 issue seems a bit drastic. It may be useful to find a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) but I'm betting that will be difficult. Do you have to stick with VS2008? VS2012 is much better in that respect.

Comment: @RogerRowland: The IDE in 2012 or 2013 itself is probably better, but the code it compiles is so overbloated that the resulting executables become megabytes larger. Plus just to convert what compiles without warnings in VS2008 into 2012 is virtually impossible.

Comment: I feel your pain - we migrated to VS2012 18 months ago and found several broken bits, but we couldn't stick with VS2008 forever. I found [this MS Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/337241/intellisense-fails-after-ncb-file-bloats-to-over-64mb-in-size) for VS2005, which may be related to the problem - info only, no use at all in practice!